# "Popular Question" & "Notable Question" badges aren't being converted into "Famous Question" badges

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

I currently have 26 "Popular Question" badges (1K views) and 6 "Notable Question" badges (2.5K views), which I'd think would definitely qualify me for more than one "Famous Question" badge (10K views).

I'm wondering if there's a glitch in the system, or if I've just misunderstood how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get those badges based on views *for that question*. That is, the 26 Popular Question badges you received was because you had 26 separate questions that *each* got 1+K views, not because 26K people total have viewed your questions.

If none of your questions have gotten 10K views *on its own*, then you don't get the Famous Question badge.

Comment: Face palm ;-) Thanks for explaining it (and for being so nice about it :-) )

Answer (score 2):

No glitch here.

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089055/pdo-prepared-statements-for-insert-and-on-duplicate-key-update-with-named-placeh)  of your six notable questions is at 9K views. The other five are all under 6K views.

So, none of them qualify for Famous Question (10K views) yet.